# Accessing property values in Annotations

Tags: java, annotations, properties

I want to access a property value in my annotation, as an attribute's value.

For ex. in my property file I have an entry expression: `3/10 * * * * ?`.

In my Scheduler class I use annotation `@Scheduled (cron = "**VALUE**")`. I want to read this value from the properties file corresponding to the expression key.

Tried doing this with `@Value`, but it returns a type of `Value` which cannot be converted to `String`.

Comment: Assuming your are using spring, take a look at this thread: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?83053-Feature-Scheduled-with-Value-cron-expression/

Answer (score 4):

From spring 3.0.1 you can do it like this
@Scheduled(cron = "${rates.refresh.cron}")

Refer to 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?83053-Feature-Scheduled-with-Value-cron-expression

However, you cannot do this for fixDelay and fixRate due to type casting problem (fixDelay expects value in long, while annotation return String only). Check Mark's comments in https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6670

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [APT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) (annotation processing tool) to replace the value in the annotation with a value from the property file.