# Setting annotation attribute from properties file

Tags: java, properties, annotations

I am using the following annotation

```
@Schedule(minute = "*/1", hour = "*", persistent=false)
```

I want the minute attribute value read from a properties file.  I have the following property file method that returns a string

```
props.getScheduledMinute() - returns "*/1", "*/2" - whatever set in the property file.
```

So if I do the following I get the warning "The value for annotation attribute Schedule.minute must be a constant expression"

```
@Schedule(minute = props.getScheduledMinute(), hour = "*", persistent=false)
```

Is there any way to feed annotation attribute value from properties file?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Looks like it was asked a long time ago, am grappling with a similar issue. Wonder if a solution was found for this??

Comment: Have a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470260/accessing-property-values-in-annotations