# Using an entry from the Spring configuration file as value for annotation property

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I'm trying to take out the name of the ElasticSearch indexName from the code and pull it into a config file.

```
@Document(indexName = "test", type = "file")
public class File {
***
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that I don't know how you/if you can put the "test" into a value in the .properties file and use it in the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using:

```
@Document(indexName = "${keyname}", type = "file")
```

In your properties file:

`keyname=test`

Comment: Sadly it doesn't seem to work. ElasticSearch sees the index as "${keyname}", instead of the value. The mapping works if I have     @Value("${keyname}")  in a different bean.

Comment: I've tested it in a simple Spring Boot app, but this feature isn't its exclusivity. I don't know your environment, but I think properties might not be available for some reason. Check out this [article](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2015/09/placeholders-support-in-value.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470260/accessing-property-values-in-annotations) stack overflow thread to see more details about using properties values. Hope it helps.